# Radix Algorithm Understanding in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

Below is the code for radix Algorithm from www.sanfoundry.com.  I don't understand the third for loop in while loop: why int i must be counted inversely and how this loop works to resign ordered elements to b[]. And one more question, what if we regard number as based 2 following the similar code? And are there any possibility to modify this code for mixture of positive and negative numbers?

```
public static void radixSort(int[] input){
  final int N = input.length;
  int exp = 1;  int[] b = new int[N];
  int max = input[0];
  for(int i = 1; i < N; i++){
    if(max <= input[i]) max = input[i];
  }
  while(max / exp > 0){
    int[] bucket = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)  bucket[(input[i] / exp ) % 10]++;
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) bucket[i] += bucket[i - 1];
    for(int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) b[--bucket[(input[i] / exp) % 10]] = input[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) input[i] = b[i];
    exp *= 10; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The third loop is inversed to make sorting stable.
- Changing the base to 2 is easy: just change the number of buckets to 2, replace `exp *= 10` with `exp *= 2` and `(input[i] / exp) % 10` with `(input[i] / exp) % 2`.
- To deal with negative numbers, you can sort negative numbers separately using their absolute value as a key and then merge a reversed result with sorted non-negative numbers.

And it looks like there is a bug in your code snippet:
it should be `int[] b = new int[N];` instead of `int[] b = new int[10];`